# How to hide black menu bar in android studio design preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to android development. I want to hide the black menu bar that appears bottom of the screen. I want to hide this because it hides the content that aligns to the bottom of the screen in preview screen . I hope following picture will make clear what do i mean.

[image]

Comment: you cant this are hardware buttons

Comment: can you explain bit where i can find it.

Comment: But why would you like to hide it, it shows you the hardware buttons simulating how your app will look like on a real device

Comment: but it hide the content like imageview or TextView beneath it.

Comment: Where i can find the hardware button setting ?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the virtual device to render a different layout. If you like to have a device without the soft-key button. You need to add your own "New Device Definition" with "New Hardware Profile".

[image]

Remember to uncheck "Has Hardware Button" in "New Hardware Profile".

You should see your new hardware profile after restarting Android Studio

[image]

Comment: *You should see your new hardware profile after restarting Android Studio* Thanks~~